# Debugger stops after async HttpClient.GetAsync() call in visual studio

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to test the follwing http request method

```
public async Task<HttpContent> Get(string url)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
// breakpoint
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
// can't reach anything below this point
        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
        {
            return content;
        }
    }
```

However, the debugger seems to be skipping the code below the 2nd comment. I'm using Visual studio 2015 RC, any ideas? I also tried checking the Tasks window and saw nothing

Edit: Found the solution

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleTests
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program program = new Program();
            var content = program.Get(@"http://www.google.com");
            Console.WriteLine("Program finished");
        }

        public async Task<HttpContent> Get(string url)
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false))
            using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
            {
                return content;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Turns out that because this was a C# console app it ended after the main thread ends I guess, because after adding a Console.ReadLine() and waiting a bit, the request did return. I guessed that C# would wait until my task execute and not end before it, but I suppose I was wrong. If anybody could elaborate on why this happened it would be nice.

Comment: This is because you have another async method `client.GetAsync(url)`. You should add breakpoint inside that method too.

Comment: I should add the breakpoint exactly where? I tried adding breakpoints on every line, even on the one calling my Get method as await, but the debugger still skips anything beyond my second GetAsync call.

Comment: @sgarcia: I believe this question is a duplicate. However, if this is incorrect, then just let me know and I'll reopen.

Comment: @StephenCleary I saw that question but when I saw ASP.NET in the answer I guessed this didn't apply to my question, since I'm doing this on a C# console application. I'll check it out for now, but if the question you pointed out doesn't apply to a C# console app please let me know as well.

Comment: @sgarcia: That answer applies to ASP.NET and UI apps, but not Console apps. A few questions: 1) Are you sure the debugger never hits the `return content` line (i.e., if you put a breakpoint there, it never gets hit)? 2) Are you blocking on the asynchronous code so it has a chance to finish before `Main` exits (and thus the program exits)? 3) If the answers to (1) and (2) are Yes, can you post a minimal, reproducible example?

Comment: Yes, I placed a breakpoint on every single line on code and it never returns. Not sure on question number 2, but my whole app is just this method and a call to it that goes like: Program p = new program(); p.Get();

Comment: @StephenCleary working on your question #3

Comment: @sgarcia: Sounds like your app just isn't waiting before it exits. You need to stop `Main` from exiting. Like do a `p.Get().Wait();` or a `p.Get(); Console.ReadKey();`.

Comment: @StephenCleary Yeah, I actually just figured that out while you wrote that and updated my question with the solution. Sorry about the rookie mistake. Any blog I could check to know why my app isn't waiting for my task to finish even with the await? I tried adding the await to the program.Get() call but it asks me to make the main method async (which I guess isn't the correct way)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

When `Main` exits, the program exits. Any outstanding asynchronous operations are canceled and their results discarded.

So, you need to block `Main` from exiting, either by blocking on the asynchronous operation or some other method (e.g., calling `Console.ReadKey` to block until the user hits a key):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Program program = new Program();
  var content = program.Get(@"http://www.google.com").Wait();
  Console.WriteLine("Program finished");
}
```

One common approach is to define a `MainAsync` that does exception handling as well:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  MainAsync().Wait();
}

static async Task MainAsync()
{
  try
  {
    Program program = new Program();
    var content = await program.Get(@"http://www.google.com");
    Console.WriteLine("Program finished");
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
  }
}
```

Note that blocking on asynchronous code is generally considered a bad idea; there are very few cases where it should be done, and a console application's `Main` method just happens to be one of them.

Comment: Thanks Stephen.  I found using your code fixed my problem too (not for the first time either).  It wasn't quite the same as the OP: my debugger stopped before the synchronous execution had even reached the end of `Main()`.  I created a `MainAsync` and used `.Wait()`, as per your example and suddenly it all came right.  Seems that async code needs to be invoked in strictly the right way.

Comment: Likewise. You should have a bitcoin donation address in your profile.

Comment: I had a similar problem with an async wcf service. Even though my service method was async and I was using await in every async call, when an exception occured, the debug exited silently, I had `try catch` in the code that was faulting, and didn't read there. I just forgot changing my async service method to return `Task` instead of `void`. After this, the exception is caught (it reaches my breakpoint inside `catch` block), and the exception is propagated to the first caller method (which is the one I changed the return from void to task).

Comment: @Stephen - I am facing issue in a web application where I am await a method with ConfigureAwait option in an async method then call Wait() on the the task returned and my control(debugger) disappears. I dont understand why. Any comments?

Comment: @AshutoshSingh: I recommend you ask your own question. I haven't seen the debugger disappear, but asking your own question will make it a lot more visible.

Comment: Sure I am trying to create a sample with same scenario. If same problem appears in sample then I think we can discuss that otherwise if its specific to my project then it may take some time to post exact scenario. Thanks btw.

Comment: @StephenCleary In sample scenario same setup is working fine but in case of my application its not working..:(

Comment: @StephenCleary  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51953743/call-to-configureawait-multiple-times-in-call-hierarchy-resulting-into-call-neve   Here is the actual issue.

Comment: thank you thank you and more thanks!! this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem following ChatGPT instructions:

```
string accountId = "12345";
string apiUrl = $"https://api.example.com/GetDashboards/{accountId}";
HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(apiUrl);  // EXPLODES HERE
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

To fix it I specify the BaseUrl:

```
using var client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiUrl);

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

var urlParameters = "";
var response = await client.GetAsync(urlParameters);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{ }
```

Comment: I have the same problem using vba.net when i call my web service class from a webMethod aspx. here ->  "client.PostAsync(Api, content)" <- is canceled

Comment: There is no such thing as VBA.Net it's either VBA in Office Apps or VB.Net

Comment: Im using vba.net on my page aspx, I call the webMethod and then call the apiRestMethod when call *"client.PostAsync(Api, content)"*  here cancel dont show any error just canceled