# Crash in DiscoveryClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:5000")

Tags: .net, identityserver4

As in title: the console app crashes while executing following line

```
disco = await DiscoveryClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:5000");
```

No exception thrown, even when I wrap it in `try catch` debug just brokes on the line; no related info in Output. Visual Studio just stops debuging the app and returns to edit mode.

Has anyone met with something similar? :( What can I try to do?

I'm using VS2015, console app is a .NETCoreApp v1.0, uses "IdentityModel": "2.0.0-rc6";.
Identity Server 4 runs on localhost:5000, .NETCoreApp v1.0.

Invoking `GetAsync` method with https://demo.identityserver.io parameter results in error descripted as well.

I'm following this tutorial: https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/dev/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html

Comment: use fiddler and see what response http://localhost:5000 is giving you (if any). async is async, and won't trigger a try/catch normally; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19865523/why-cant-i-catch-an-exception-from-async-code

Comment: localhost:5000 works properly when requested with fiddler and chrome, returns json while navigated to /.well-known... just like in the tutorial I updated original post with.

I turned off just my code, but with the same result.

Also I've wrapped in in try catch so there should be something: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383310/catch-an-exception-thrown-by-an-async-method

Comment: Don't request it will fiddler or chrome, use fiddler to monitor your application's attempt at requesting it (if at all)

Comment: Thanks. I tried it. I used View on IdentityServer. I could request .well-known without issues via browser. Next, I ran ConsoleApp to test it and again app crashed on the line. Fiddler just showed a bunch of 201 and 202 results with anonymous jsons from vshub. Did I miss something or misused the tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it was working, but I misused async/await calling in Console App. How to do it properly is explanied here: [Debugger stops after async HttpClient.GetAsync() call in visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31281073/debugger-stops-after-async-httpclient-getasync-call-in-visual-studio)