# ExecuteAsync() causing hard crash with no exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, restsharp

Here's the question: What would be stopping this code from executing this http request?

Here's the setup: I am doing a project that has multiple API's, and this is one method that is called within the first to the second for validation info. The method, in theory should make the request, send the model to the second service, and return back with something that is returned at the end of this method.

When running both API's locally with breakpoints to see if they are being hit, the second never gets hit, because the moment the ExecuteAsync() line is hit, it hard crashes, then restarts the first API. I dont think I did anything wrong here, but there isn't any sort of stack trace or exception that it throws at me, even if I put it into a try/catch. Is this a known issue or am I just doing something wrong here?

```cs
        public async Task<SharkTankValidationResponseModel> CheckIfValidRequest(SharkTankValidationModel requestModel)
        {
            // Setup rest client
            RestClient userRestClient = new RestClient(endpoint + "SharkTank/Validate");
            RestRequest userRequest = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            // New request object for body

            userRequest.AddJsonBody(requestModel);
            // HTTP Request
            IRestResponse response = await userRestClient.ExecuteAsync(userRequest);
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SharkTankValidationResponseModel>(response.Content);
        }
```

On the top level, this is is how it is called. The model is being made correctly without issue, and I can step through the code all the way up to the execute function before it just hard crashes

```cs
                SharkTankValidationModel model = await makeSharkTankValidationModel(Method.GET, SharkTankConstants.GET_ALL_CLIENT_CATEGORY, null);
                SharkTankValidationResponseModel validationModel = await sharkTank.CheckIfValidRequest(model);
```

Gif for reference of steps running through debugger and the sudden crash
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAZoT.jpg

Comment: Did you forget to await `CheckIfValidRequest`?

Comment: Double checking, I did await the method on the top level, so that wouldn't be the issue

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. My guess is somewhere in the call stack you are missing an await.

Comment: Added the top level calling. It's being correctly awaited as far as I can see

Comment: This seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31281073/debugger-stops-after-async-httpclient-getasync-call-in-visual-studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, figured it out after finally trying it in a way that let me see an exception in a response. The error was the following:

```cs
ActualMessage: "A possible object cycle was detected. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 64. Consider using ReferenceHandler.Preserve on JsonSerializerOptions to support cycles."
BytePositionInLine: null
ClassName: "System.Text.Json.JsonException"
Data: null
ExceptionMethod: null
HResult: -2146233088
HelpURL: null
InnerException: null
LineNumber: null
Message: "A possible object cycle was detected. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 64. Consider using ReferenceHandler.Preserve on JsonSerializerOptions to support cycles."
Path: "$.requestorRoles.Subject.Claims.Subject.Claims.Subject.Claims.Subject.Claims.Subject.Claims.Subject.Claims.Subject.Claims.Subject.Claims.Subject.Claims.Subject.Claims.Subject.Claims.Subject.Claims.Subject.Claims.Subject.Claims.Subject.Claims.Subject.Claims.Subject.Claims.Subject.Claims.Subject.Claims.Subject.Claims.Subject.AuthenticationType"
RemoteStackIndex: 0
RemoteStackTraceString: null
Source: "System.Text.Json"
StackTraceString: "   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonExcep
WatsonBuckets: null
```

Now the object I was using for a model was using microsoft's default claims object types for passing forward the claims. This apparently made the json serializer freak out and loop through itself over and over, and just hard crash when it found a loop.

The fix was just making a custom object type to map those claims to, and literally there were no issues using any of the 3 different HTTP method call types. Long story short, dont use the default claims type for things. Just makes issues.

Comment: Please describe the approach that you used to see the exception in the response.

Answer (score 0):

Based on RestClient's documentation, `ExecuteAsync` does not throw an exception, but instead populates `response.ErrorException` and `response.ErrorMessage` if `response.IsSuccessful` is `false`. If you don't need access to the response StatusCode and only care about the body, just use `PostAsync<T>` instead.

```cs
public async Task<SharkTankValidationResponseModel> CheckIfValidRequest(SharkTankValidationModel requestModel)
{
    // Setup rest client
    RestClient userRestClient = new RestClient(endpoint);
    RestRequest userRequest = new RestRequest("SharkTank/Validate")
        .AddJsonBody(requestModel);
    // HTTP Request
    IRestResponse response = await userRestClient.PostAsync<SharkTankValidationResponseModel>(userRequest);
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Gave this a try, but alas, the same issue persists. I copied the last messages in the debugger to help in case it might help figure the issue out?
https://pastebin.com/GeUT4Qtz

Like I get that in theory it SHOULD have at the very least thrown back an is successful bool and such, but it quite literally never gets to that point. The program just fails on the execute step, which isn't something that used to happen in my past experience with RestSharp

Comment: @kmanrulze, I haven't used RestClient much since dotnet core came out. Have you confirmed the version of dotnet you're targeting is supported by your version of RestClient? Have you attempted to serialize your `requestModel` independently? You may want to look at the standard HttpClient, HttpClientFactory, and injecting the client into your class. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests

Comment: Hmm, I have that a try just now as well. Seemed like a pretty nice alternative, though when I ran through the breakpoints, the same kind of hard crash happened with no stack trace and generally the same thing as that pastebin above. Leads me to think maybe something deeper is the problem? Middleware or otherwise causing an issue perhaps?

Comment: Just an update, I tried a third different way to try and catch some issue, if any, and found an exception thrown like this: `{"A possible object cycle was detected. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 64. Consider using ReferenceHandler.Preserve on JsonSerializerOptions to support cycles."}`
Perhaps this points to something? Once again, my thoughts are something to do with middleware ordering or something, honestly. Might help find whats wrong